# Parameterized IReports, SQL statement with a LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, parameters, jasper-reports

I designed an *JasperReports*'s report with passing 2 parameters into a `LIKE clause` as follows but the report won't generate. Can you please help?

`name` and `date` are two string parameters I created

```
SELECT * from sessions WHERE Name LIKE '%$P{name}%' AND Logintime LIKE '%$P{date}%'
```

I could get the whole table value when I removed the two parameters though

```
SELECT * from sessions WHERE Name LIKE '%%' AND Logintime LIKE '%%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the view. I found the answer anyway. I'd like to post it here.. Just change it from,

```
SELECT * from sessions WHERE Name LIKE '%$P{name}%' AND Logintime LIKE '%$P{date}%'
```

to

```
SELECT * from sessions WHERE Name LIKE '%$!P{name}%' AND Logintime LIKE '%$!P{date}%'
```

then it works fine :)